# Induced subgraphs in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, subgraph

I have a graph in neo4j, and for a given node N, I would like to find all nodes that are reachable in a path of no longer than P steps from N, as well as all links between that set of nodes.  It seems like this could be possible with either Cypher or the Traversal framework; is one preferred over the other?  I'm doing this from Java with an embedded database, and I will need to perform further queries on the subgraph.  I've poked around and haven't found any conclusive answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think cypher is the most concise way of getting your desired data, querying for variable length paths, some collecting and refining:

If n is the internal id of your node `N` and your `P` is 5:

```
START begin = node(n)             // or e.g. index lookup
MATCH p = (begin)<-[r*..5]-(end)  // match all paths of length up to 5
WITH distinct nodes(p) as nodes   // collect the nodes contained in the paths
MATCH (x)<-[r]-(y)                // find all relationships between nodes
WHERE x in nodes and y in nodes   // which were found earlier
RETURN distinct x,r,y             // and deduplicate as you find all pairs twice
```

It might not be the most efficient way, but at least the execution plan explanation in http://console.neo4j.org/ suggests that the `y in nodes` is considered before the `MATCH (x)-[r]-(y)`.

I couldn't think of a way to avoid matching the relationships twice, therefore the `distinct` in the return statement.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!  It seems that creating a new embedded database and putting the graph into it is the best way to perform additional operations on that subgraph.